# How to get the last element of a sequence in XPath?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

In Ruby we can access an array with negative numbers like `array[-1]` to get the last object in the array.  How do I do this using XPath?

I can't do this:

```
result = node.xpath('.//ROOT/TAG[-1]/KEY_NAME')
```

I found a solution here on Stack Overflow, but that is a query that just changes the upper limit to get elements. This could return one last item or last item and prevous.

What if I want to get only the prevous element like `array[-2]` in Ruby?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can access the last element in XPath using `last()` in a predicate.

```
node.xpath('.//ROOT/TAG[last()]/KEY_NAME')
```

And use `[last()-1]` for the second-to-last position.

Comment: Use `[last()-1]` for the second-to-last position.