# how to change a number in xpath with any number in selenium ide

Tags: xpath

I want to get some text by the xpath and that text appears in the last row of a table whose number of rows is constantly changing.

I want to change the number 6 here with any number. Is it possible?

```
//*[@id='entire_ajax_table']/tbody/tr[6]/td/span/input
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the last element of a sequence in XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141347/how-to-get-the-last-element-of-a-sequence-in-xpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`last()` gives you access to the last element in a sequence.

```
//*[@id='entire_ajax_table']/tbody/tr[last()]/td/span/input
```

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted than, showing other users that it worked. Have a look at the [FAQ].

Comment: I do not see an "accept" option. Tried to vote up, but it requires 15 reputation. I did not find anything related to this topic in the FAQ. What shall I do?

Comment: It should be some checkmark directly below these voting-buttons.

Comment: yeah, i hadnt noticed it. Done!